# If the integral is zero when is the integrand zero?

Tags: integration, vector-fields, calculus

Using Stoke's theorem we prove that the curl of the Electric field vanishes. This would be possible only if the integrand is zero when the integral is zero.

Comment: $\int_{-1}^{+1}\mathrm dx\ \sin(x)=0$, but $\sin(x)\neq 0$ (ae)

Comment: An integral is effectively a sum. 1 + 2 - 3 = 0...

Comment: Might [math.se] be better suited for this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the integral of a function is zero, this does not necessarily imply that the function is zero everywhere. An easy counterexample is the sine function, for which $\int_{-1}^1\sin x\,\mathrm{d}x=0$, but $\sin x$ does not identically vanish on $[-1,1]$. However, if the integral vanishes for all possible regions of integration, then the function is zero everywhere. Take sine above: since $\int_0^1\sin x\,\mathrm{d}x\simeq 0.5$, the sine function is not zero everywhere. But Stokes' theorem tells you that the integral of the curl vanishes no matter what region of integration you take. The conclusion is that the curl vanishes identically.

The formal proof of this is [not easy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/219738/showing-that-f-0-a-e-if-for-any-measurable-set-e-int-e-f-0).